# What does "bulk concentration" mean?

Tags: biochemistry, concentration, geochemistry, etymology

In biogeochemistry/ecosystem models, the concentration of phytoplankton in sea water is often termed "bulk concentration" with units mol P/m^3 (moles of phosphorus per cubic meter, assuming that we know how the stoichiometry of the organic composition of phytoplankton, which is often the case in models). The unit makes sense for "normal" concentrations. What does "bulk" mean in this case?

Comment: That depends on the context which is known within biogeochemistry/ecosystem models. The unit makes sense for any concentration. By the explicit BULK they may mean in the whole water volume.

Comment: So in the model output, there are ion concentrations also in mol X per cubic meter (e.g. carbonate concentration, phosphate concentration, nitrate concentrations...) - and bulk phytoplankton concentration.

Comment: @ouranos, You can share the original text or a portion of so that readers can understand the context. Bulk concentration has many connotations. In electrochemistry it has a different meaning.

Comment: At a guess, they mean *average* concentration throughout the whole sample. The critters in the water would be specks of high-concentration phosphorus, and the liquid lower (unless it came from farm effluent).